# How to check whether SMP is enabled or disabled in the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I was wondering how can I check on my running machine, whether the kernel is configured for SMP or not? Of course,  I can look into the kernel `.config` file and can search for it. But, the question is let's say I don't have a source code, how will I check the SMP configuration? Is there any *proc* file to check it?

The following says that I have no multi-cores:

```
#cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor               : 1
cpu model               : Broadcom BMIPS5000 V1.1  FPU V0.1
BogoMIPS                : 651.26
cpu MHz                 : 1305.018
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 64
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : no
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

The output of `uname -a` says:

```
Linux 136.170.193.3 3.3.8-2.4 #2 SMP Fri Dec 13 07:11:03 EST 2013 mips GNU/Linux
```

A bit confusing here. Someone on the comments suggested me to check `uname -a` . I am not sure whether the results are reliable or not. Can I assume  that with the keyword SMP produced by `uname -a`, the kernel is configured as SMP?

Comment: does uname -a tell that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I assume
>   that with the keyword SMP produced by uname -a, the kernel is
>   configured as SMP?

Yes. The version string returned by uname is generated when kernel is compiled.

Answer (score 3):

The "top" command may help towards this,  you can see the list of running tasks and the current processor id on which they are executing by using -

> top -H

then press `f` to go to field selection, and `j` enable the CPU core column, and `Enter` to display.

the core information will be displayed under `P` column.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux configuration, check for `CONFIG_SMP=y`. If this configuration is set then your kernel runs with `Symmetric multiprocessing`.

Find your config file in /boot (usually file name as `config-$(uname -r)` on ubuntu) or else check in the `/proc/config.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of embedded systems,

It is `CONFIG_SMP=y`, not `CONFIG_CMP=y`

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_SMP
```

In case of Desktop,
find your config file from /boot directory and grep for `CONFIG_SMP`, it should be `=y`

Answer (score 0):

just check using

> ps

command and check the cpu id.

You can even use the

> ps -ef

Comment: Do not see what it have to do with the SMP configuration at compile time.