# Can't find WSL kernel directory not in /usr/src and not in /lib/modules

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyperthreading, smp

I am not a developer, and don't have enough experience with Linux.
I am a data scientist and wants to know how to improve my performance using my CPUs better.

I have a linux VM with 2 physical CPUs, with 15 logical cores with two logical processors per core, (so 30 logical/virtual processors).

System information: With `lsb release -a` I get:

> No LSB modules are available
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
>
> Release         18.04
>
> Code Name:      bionic

From the website: [how-to-determine-the-number-of-physical-cpus-on-linux](https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/how-to-determine-the-number-of-physical-cpus-on-linux/) I can understand that the **amount of my virtual processors is greater than the number of my physical processors**

According to the website, potentially, I can use Hyper-Threading.

**I want to know if my kernel is configured as SMP so I can actually use Hyper-threading**.

I have a 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft WSL kernel ( I used `uname --all`) which gives:

> Linux hykindev03 **4.4.0-18362-Microsoft** #836-Microsoft Mon May 05
>   16:04:00 PST 220 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

One way to get it is with the methods here: 
[how-to-check-whether-smp-is-enabled-or-disabled-in-the-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852902/how-to-check-whether-smp-is-enabled-or-disabled-in-the-kernel)

The problem is, I can't find the kernel config file, because it doesn't exist in **/proc directory**.
I understand it should be in the kernel directory, but I also can't find it, it is not in **/usr/src** (and I don't have the **kernels** directory there neither) nor in **/lib/modules**.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Normal Ubuntu linux-modules-${KVER} packages install a /boot/config-${KVER} file containing the kernel configuration. Is that also true for Ubuntu on WSL2? (Here, I'm using ${KVER} to represent the kernel version.)

Comment: I think for a non-SMP kernel, there will be no more than one CPU listed in /proc/cpuinfo or /sys/devices/system/cpu/. (The reverse is not necessarily true.)